# How to get rows between two rows with specific text?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ocr, python-tesseract

I have this dataframe, I extracted this through and image using PyTesseract. But it extracted all the irrelevant data like signatures and stamps. I only want data from 'ASSETS' row to 'Total Liablities' Row. I tried

```
bs = bs[(bs['Purticulars'] == 'ASSETS') & (df['Purticulars'] == 'TOTAL LIABILITIES')
```

but doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first find the indices of the rows that have the values "ASSETS" and "TOTAL LIABILITIES" in the "Particulars" column.

And once you get the row indices, you can very easily find all the rows in between.

here:

```
assets_index = df.index[df['Purticulars'] == 'ASSETS'].tolist()[0]
liabilities_index = df.index[df['Purticulars'] == 'TOTAL LIABILITIES'].tolist()[0]
result = df.loc[assets_index:liabilities_index]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['Purticulars'].isin(['ASSETS','TOTAL LIABILITIES']).cumsum().eq(1) | df.eq('TOTAL LIABILITES')]
```

or

```
d = {'ASSETS':True,'TOTAL LIABILITIES':False}

m = df['Purticulars'].map(d).ffill().fillna(False) | df.eq('TOTAL LIABILITES')

df.loc[m]
```